# app on bluemix does not start up says 0 of 1 instance running

Tags: ibm-cloud

My app on bluemix does not start up says `0 of 1 instance running`, how do I fix it?

```
Starting app mytwitinfluapp in org xyz@in.ibm.com / space dev as xyz@in.ibm.com...
OK

0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 failing
FAILED
Start unsuccessful

logs indicate the following
2014-08-25T12:37:38.31+0530 [DEA]     OUT Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2014-08-25T12:38:06.79+0530 [DEA]     OUT Removing crash for app with id e7c454db-1d71-486d-ae8c-1fce17b978ec
2014-08-25T12:38:06.79+0530 [DEA]     OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) with guid e7c454db-1d71-486d-ae8c-1fce17b978ec
2014-08-25T12:38:06.79+0530 [DEA]     OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with guid e7c454db-1d71-486d-ae8c-1fce17b978ec
2014-08-25T12:42:46.15+0530 [DEA]     OUT Removing crash for app with id e7c454db-1d71-486d-ae8c-1fce17b978ec
2014-08-25T12:42:46.15+0530 [DEA]     OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) with guid e7c454db-1d71-486d-ae8c-1fce17b978ec
2014-08-25T12:42:46.15+0530 [DEA]     OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with guid e7c454db-1d71-486d-ae8c-1fce17b978ec
```

Comment: can you attempt to deploy and then give more of the output of:    


cf logs <appname> --recent

Comment: Hi i know this is old, but for others with the same problem... in your server.js or app.js make sure you have something along the lines of

`app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);`
`var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'));`

Answer (score 2):

The key error message in the log output is this one:
`2014-08-25T12:37:38.31+0530 [DEA]     OUT Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections`

The message means that your app is either listening on the wrong port (as jsloyer stated) or you have pushed an app that doesn't listen on a  port but you didn't set the --no-route option.

What is happening under the covers is the health manager is polling the route (url) that has been configured for your app to determine if the application is still alive. As no response came back from your app then it is killed that instance of the app.

Answer (score 2):

This usually indicates some error in your code (app.js, manifest.yml) or code in any other language. I found the following technique very useful to debug this situation by using the cf command

cf logs app-name  --recent

This will dump the logs when you try to push your app onto Bluemix. You can use the above command also if your app crashes suddenly while executing.

Checkout my post [Spicing up IBM Bluemix cloud app  with MongoDB and NodeExpress](http://gigadom.wordpress.com/2014/08/07/spicing-up-a-ibm-bluemix-cloud-app-with-mongodb-and-nodeexpress/)
I used this technique many times while debugging my app

Answer (score 1):

This is usually caused by a runtime error such as binding to the wrong port to an error in the startup of your app, as someone mentioned above can you please post the output of cf logs mytwitinfluapp --recent?

Answer (score 0):

The info you have provided is insufficient to diagnose.I assume that you are using cf command

prompt.for detail analysis about the failure,please provide log file of recent run

Answer (score 0):

If you are using something like Java verify that your MANIFEST.MF file is correct according with the bluemix domain. Also if you are using other runtime different to Java verify that your app has been set correctly to point you bluemix environment.

This article helped to understand how to deploy applications in bluemix:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-hangman-app/index.html